# Web service for simple data logging and viewing

Tags: web, logs

I have an app with a limited number of users that registers a couple of different buttons being pushed. I want to log these actions online and provide a simple webinterface with a summary over the collected data, e.g the total number of pushes for each button, button pushes per day, maybe even some diagrams etc.. it would probably be easy enough to implement this in Node.js or something, but maybe there's some ready-made solution already out there?

Comment: I looking for something which is reasonably similar - https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/55292/ajax-based-debug-trace

Answer (score 1):

As you mention you can use Node.js as your backend API what about frontend?
I suggest from my point of view to use frameworks such as AngularJS or VueJS so you can handle your backend data easily and with a good performance.

Also, with Node.js it will be better to use MongoDB as your database,

Good Luck!
Happy Coding